# Sorting an array so that the index does not move?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, asort

How would I sort an array, in that the values move and the index's stay still. I wrote this code below, although the answer it gave is not ideal.

```
$array = array(6,2,22,15,33,40,30,70,65);
asort($array,);
print_r($array);
```

Now this  sorts the values, but the index moves with the value. I get the answer;

```
Array ( [1] => 2 [0] => 6 [3] => 15 [2] => 22 [6] => 30 [4] => 33 [5] => 40 [8] => 65 [7] => 70 )
```

Although I would like it to show as the following;

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 6 [2] => 15, etc.
```

Thank you!

Comment: ***a**ssociative  sort()*

Comment: Use sort() rather than asort()

Comment: This is a paradox... you want the indexes to stick, but not to stick... as @MarkBaker says: use sort()

Answer (score 0):

Use **[array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)***

It merges two arrays into one using the first as a set of keys, and the second one as set of values for the new array.

So basically you only need to get the original keys and the sorted values, and then feed them to `array_combine()`.

```
$a = [
  'a' => 'orange',
  'b' => 'apple',
  'o' => 'banana',
];

$tmp = $a;
sort($tmp);
$result = array_combine(array_keys($a), $tmp);

var_dump($a, $result);
```

You can try it out [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/53b8a21d4d74b438cf2c53e8445a175a7e734865).

Cheers.

---

<sub>*:available from PHP 5</sub>.